# How can I gather an existing Angular project to and existing Node.Js project

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express

I have an Angular project which is already deployed to heroku and I also have a Node.Js API REST which is also deployed to heroku.
The thing is, they are different projects with diferent URLs, but they work together. Is there a way I could put them together in the server and have only one URL?

I'm doing this:

frontend-aplication.herokuapp.com  -> backend-aplication.herokuapp.com

I'd like to have this:

http://application.herokuapp.com

Thank you

It's my Node project.

```
router.post('/auth/authenticate',async (req,res,next)=>{  
   return res.status(200).send();
});
```

It's my angular call

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this.http.post(this.SERVER_URL+"/auth/authenticate",this.body)
    .subscribe((result: any) => {
          resolve(result);
     },
     (error) => {
      reject(error);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this, is code your project to handle both apps inside the same project. I don't know what each project is like, but your front-end probably is like a "just-serve-front-files" maybe a server render for react or angular. But your can achieve that any way. Just Google something like "nodejs backend XYZ serving angular"